# how can send command from Rviz to Arduino?

Tags: arduino, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi . i try to build robot like turtlebot for slam . how can i send command from Rviz to Arduino ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250128/how-can-send-command-from-rviz-to-arduino-?/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2016-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's a pretty open-ended question. The open-ended answer is that you use an rivz plugin or an rviz tool to send the command.

Which rviz tool or plugin to use and how to use it depends on what kind of command you want to send.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0